# How to expose deployment as a service in 2.1-ee?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I created a service and use nodeport etc but couldn't access the service.

I created a web-service.yaml file with the following content and used kubectl to create the Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-service
  labels:
    app: web-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: webserver
```

and the webserver.yaml file with the following Deployment details

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webserver
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: webserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webserver
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

In your deployment, label is run=webserver, but in your service, label is app=webserver. The service uses app=webserver as a Selector, through which it selects three pods that have the label "app" set to "webserver". In this case none of the pods has the label "app" so the deployment is not successfully exposed as a service. The label names and values in the deployment and service should match.